# How can i use a property name passed as paramenter?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a function that do something with an array of objects and i need to have just the name of property of another object to access it but i get undefined.
It seems that i can't use a string to access to the object

```
function myFunction(arrayOfObjects, propName)
{
     for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++)
     {
         //This will give undefined, propName is simply a string coming from Object.keys()
         arrayOfObjects[i].propName = something;
     }

    return something;
}
```

Call to the function

```
var arrayOfNameProp = Object.keys(myObject);

var x = myFunction(arrayOfObjects, arrayOfNameProp[0]);
```

Comment: Please post an example of your Array

Comment: Typing your question title + "javascript" into Google would have led you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760186/ in now time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pass it as a `string`, use bracket notation `[propName]` instead of dot notation `.propName`

```
arrayOfObjects[i][propName] = something;
```