# Pass object and properties by reference in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, reference

I've seen lots of questions about passing objects by reference in Javascript, but not the object and properties by reference. Is it possible?

Right now I only found a way to do it by going through some type of logic like this, which is terribly inconvenient:

```
let multipliers = {
    none:1,
    sin:2,
    cos:3,
    tan:4,
    atan:5,
}

incMultiplier(shapesMovements[index], "rotation", "x", "sin")

function incMultiplier(shapeMovement, kind, dimension, multiplier){

    var numOfKeys = Object.keys(multipliers).length;
    
    if(kind === "rotation"){
    
        if(dimension === "x"){
        
            if(multiplier === "sin"){
                if(shapeMovement.rotation.x.multiplier !== numOfKeys){
                    shapeMovement.rotation.x.multiplier += 1
                }else{
                    shapeMovement.rotation.x.multiplier = 1
                }
            }
        
        }
    
    }

}
```

I'd just like to increase the property value by one with whatever object and property I've thrown into that function.

I've seen [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760186/how-to-pass-an-object-property-as-a-parameter-javascript) where you can pass parameters, but this looks to assemble a new object, and is not by reference. I need to actually edit the values on the object's properties.

Originally, this is what I was trying, and it did not seem to alter the object on a global level. Only locally to the function:

```
incMultiplier(shapesMovements[index].rotation.x.multiplier)

function incMultiplier(multiplier){

    var numOfKeys = Object.keys(multipliers).length;
    if(multiplier !== numOfKeys){
        multiplier = multiplier + 1 
    }else{
        multiplier = 1
    }

    // always results in the same number. 
    // Does not keep increasing every time the function is called.
    console.log(multiplier); 
}
```

Comment: If im wrong correct me, Objects are inherently passed by reference.

Comment: What do you mean by "*and properties*"? An object *is* its properties.

Comment: What do `multipliers` and `shapesMovements` look like?

Comment: You can avoid two of those `if` statements by using `shapeMovement[kind][dimension].multiplier`. Or, if you never refer to other properties of `shapeMovement`, why not pass the `shapesMovements[index].rotation.x` object directly, and only manipulate its `.multiplier` property?

Comment: This object can have all sorts of different properties, but in the end, I'm always increasing the multiplier. If I pass the object and all it's properties, it does not permantly alter that object on a global level. It only alters it in the scope of the function.

Comment: "*It only alters it in the scope of the function.*" can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do: `shapeMovement[kind][dimension][multiplier]` ?

Comment: "*If I pass the object, it does not permantly alter that object on a global level*" - actually, it does. Please show us the code where you tried that.

Comment: shapesMovements[index].position.x could also be passed to the function. (position or rotation, x, y, z, among others.) It always ends in multiplier though.

Comment: adiga, yes, if that works, that would be nice.

Comment: Not seeing where and how you define `multipliers` (plural). As such, perhaps you have a logical error. You could always do some `console.log()`ing to sort this out.

Comment: I added an example where the value does not keep increasing, meaning it does not globally alter my value.

Comment: I added the multiplier object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Originally, this is what I was trying

You're not passing an object with its properties there. You're passing the value of a single property, and assignments to `multiplier` do indeed just overwrite the local variable in the function. You need to pass an object and explicitly assign to its property:

```
function incMultiplier(valueObj) {
    var numOfKeys = Object.keys(multipliers).length;
    if (valueObj.multiplier !== numOfKeys) {
        valueObj.multiplier++;
    } else {
        valueObj.multiplier = 1
    }
}

incMultiplier(shapesMovements[index].rotation.x)
incMultiplier(shapesMovements[index].position.x)
incMultiplier(shapesMovements[index].rotation.y)
incMultiplier(shapesMovements[index].rotation.z)
```

It's not necessary to pass the whole `shapesMovements` objects and everything nested within them, passing a single mutable object is enough.